# mysql sum calculation in stored procedure by particular year

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

my table is :tbl_fee_payment_history

```
pk_int_fph_id   fk_int_student_id   int_fph_amount  dat_fph_date
        1           1                 10000         2013-12-11
        2           2                  5000         2013-11-11
        3           1                  5000         2014-12-16
        4           3                  5000         2013-10-19
        5           4                  5000         2014-01-11
```

i want to create an stored procedure that will return the total amount pay in an particular year.

like;

```
call csp_fee(2013); return value as 20000.
```

Comment: Start with the official doc here http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-tutorials-stored-procedures.html

Comment: take the IN variable, use it in your where clause

Comment: plz give me an detailed answer ....because i am  new in sql ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NOt tested but i hope it will work.

```
 DELIMITER $$ 
 drop procedure if exists csp_fee$$
  CREATE  PROCEDURE `csp_fee`(
     IN in_year DECIMAL(18,2),
     OUT in sum_year DECIMAL(18,2))
     BEGIN
     SELECT round(sum(int_fph_amount),2)
      INTO sum_year
      FROM tbl_fee_payment_history where        
      DATE_FORMAT(dat_fph_date,'%Y') = in_year;
   END;
   $$
   DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: it's not working ..............i'am using xampp to do this on mysql .....is there any problem with this !

Comment: friendzzzzzz....i got it..                               as like this.........!   DELIMITER //
 
  CREATE  PROCEDURE CSP_tbl_fph_fees(IN in_year INT(10),OUT sum_year INT(10))
     BEGIN
     SELECT round(sum(int_fph_amount))INTO sum_year
      FROM tbl_fee_payment_history where        
     EXTRACT(YEAR FROM dat_fph_date) = in_year;
   END//
DELIMITER ;

call CSP_tbl_fph_fees(2013,@sum_year);
select @sum_year;